# JSON Decoder Error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 22 (char 21)

Tags: python, json, kivy, delimiter

```py
print(signupEmail, signupPassword)
signupInfo = str({f'\"{signupEmail}\":{{"password":\""{signupPassword}\", "Username":\"{signupUsername}\"}}'})
signupInfo = signupInfo.replace(".","-")
signupInfo = signupInfo.replace("\'","")
to_database = json.loads(signupInfo)
print((to_database))
requests.patch(url = self.url,json = to_database)
self.strng.get_screen('loginscreen').manager.current = 'loginscreen'
```

When I try to run this, I get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 22 (char 21)`

Comment: Have viewed quite a few solutions but none worked out for me. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you use code format when posting codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, when you encounter an error like this, I would first try to step through the code in a debugger, or at the least, print out the string giving you trouble.  If you had done that, you would have seen `signupInfo` contains:

```
{"(signupEmail)":{"password":""(signupPassword)", "Username":"(signupUsername)"}}
```

Clearly there are two quotes before the password.  If you fix the line that creates the string, removing the double quote, it will work:

```
#                                                    v <--- get rid of extra quote that was here
signupInfo = str({f'\"{signupEmail}\":{{"password":\"{signupPassword}\", "Username":\"{signupUsername}\"}}'})
```